# Perl : Printing a hash with multiple values for single key

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I have  hash with multiple values to a key. How to print multiple values of key in a hash independently?

```
# HASH with multiple values for each key
my %hash = ( "fruits" => [ "apple" , "mango" ], "vegs" => ["Potato" , "Onion"]);

# SET UP THE TABLE
print "<table border='1'>";
print "<th>Category</th><th>value1</th><th>value2</th>";    

#Print key and values in hash in tabular format
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {
    print "<tr><td>".$key."</td>";
    print "<td>".@{$hash{$key}}."</td>";
}
```

*** Current Output: ***

```
 Category  Value1         Value2
 fruits    apple mango
 vegs      Potato Onion
```

*** Desired Output: ***

```
 Category  Value1   Value2
 fruits    apple     mango
 vegs      Potato    Onion
```

Comment: Use another `foreach` loop for the values. Or use `map` to wrap them in `<td>...</td>` and print that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the second line of your loop with

```
print "<td>$_</td>" for @{ $hash{$key} };
```

Which will loop over each item in the array reference and wrap them in `td` tags.